# jQuery Coda-Slider Expand-Collapse

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, coda-slider

I am using the Coda-Slider ( http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/ ) for a project, and I would like to add a functionality:

So, clicking on the tabs at the top will slide from one panel to another.

I WANT:
When you click on a tab that's already the current panel, I want the pannel (content box) to collapse.

I've tried toggling classes, toggling slides.... nothing works...

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want the slide to collapse, then reveal the next slide by toggling open?...As opposed to the current slide transition?

Comment: No, I mean: If the slider is open and you click a tab that is not the active slide, I want it to slide as usual. BUT if you click on the active tab, it will collapse the slide. Clicking on any tab after that would re-expand the slider.

Comment: Imagine having a bar with 4 tabs. Clicking on any tab ould then reveal the slider. You can navigate going from one tab to another. Clicking on the active tab would collapse the slider.